# In reinforcement learning, what is the difference between optimal policy and piece-wise optimal policy?

Tags: machine-learning, policy, dynamic-controls, reinforcement-learning, control-theory

How can we define optimal policy and piece wise optimal policy?

I guess it depends whether it is a continuous time or discrete time problem. For discrete time both should be same. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add an answer myself.

The piece-wise optimal policy would be the one in which we select optimal action greedily (i.e. optimal only for next instant). However optimal would be the one in which we select the policy over a time horizon (as in episodic MDP). The length of time horizon depends upon the application.